# What are the rules for making your own conduit KOs in nonmetallic junction boxes?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec

Some North American electrical boxes (usually nonmetallic ones) lack conduit knockouts, as they are designed solely to clamp NM cable.  Unfortunately, some devices (the [RIB series](https://www.functionaldevices.com/products/building-automation/details/RIBU1C/) of enclosed, UL listed relays, for instance) use their own enclosure with a conduit nipple providing a wiring chase to the box they're connected to.

Does one need a conduit knockout provisioned in the box in order to attach a nonmetallic conduit (nipple) to it, or can one drill an appropriately sized hole in the box, then use a non-metallic locknut to attach the conduit to the box?  What Code provisions apply?

Comment: @Mazura -- the device is in a nonmetallic box with a nonmetallic, threaded nipple molded into it -- it has no facility for grounding as it doesn't need one.

Comment: @Mazura -- I retitled the question based on your feedback

Comment: No laws, I can think about,other than command sense. Do not so many holes ,Can not put on lock nuts or box weakens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to drill a hole in plastic, in fact a lot of them don't even come with knockouts - for example

http://www.carlonsales.com/productdrawings/E987N.pdf

The zip boxes and others with integral NM clips - I doubt they are listed for use with conduit but even if they are, I'd use one like that linked above.

Comment: we regularly drill plastic boxes, the only thing I can think of the box needs to be large enough for the "box fill" and needs to be accessible, I.E. not covered with sheetrock/ buried in a wall.